# Adding a file that saved in Onedrive to API request

Tags: office-js, restsharp, word-addins, word-web-addins

```
RestSharp.RestRequest.AddFile
```

this allows to add a locally saved file to the REST request. But how it can be done for a file that saved in a cloud location. I'm creating an add-in for Word 365. And also using Office javascript API. Inside add-ins web project I have a C# controller to make a POST request to another API endpoint. For that POST request I need to add the saved Word file in Onedrive. I tried with RestSharp.RestRequest.AddFile method but didn't work.

Comment: Please show your code and explain exactly what you mean by "didn't work".